# At how many points $f(x)$ is continuous in $\left[ 0, 4 \pi\right]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, continuity

Given $$f(x)= \begin{cases} x^2+1 & x \in \mathbb Q^c \\
                           \tan x & x \in\mathbb Q 
\end{cases}$$

At how many points $f(x)$ is continous in $\left[ 0, 4 \pi\right]$

I think it is continous at all irrationals, since if $a$ is an irrational , then $a^+$ and $a^-$ are also irrationals  so we have both left and right limits equal to $f(a)$. Any corrections?

Comment: Look at the points where $x^2+1=\tan(x)$.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by $a^+$ and $a^-$, but your reasoning is wrong; there's a sequence of rationals converging to any irrational, so the values at those points must _also_ converge to $f(a)$.

Comment: yes i agree my reasoning is wrong...what i meant was $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x)=a^2+1$ when $a$ is irrational and same follows for left hand limit. But after a thought i understood that $a^+$ may be rational or irrational

Comment: I request you to accept an answer below and close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using the sequential definition of continuity at a point $x$, whenever $x_n \to x$, we must have that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.

So let $x \in [0,4\pi]$. We know that there exists a sequence $x_n$ of rationals converging to $x$, and a sequence $y_n$ made entirely of irrationals converging to $x$. Hence, if $f$ were continuous at $x$, then both $x_n^2 + 1$ and $\tan y_n$ must converge to the same quantity $f(x)$. But this at least implies that $x^2+1 = \tan x$.

There are seemingly three solutions of this equation in the given interval, which I found by Wolfram Alpha. Now, I leave you to show that the given function is actually continuous at these points (So now, you have to consider a general sequence converging to this point, not just a sequence entirely made of rationals or irrationals, and show that the function value also converges).

Hence, there are three points of continuity in the interval.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:suppose $f(x)=\begin{cases}x & x \in \mathbb{Q}\\2-x & x \in \mathbb{Q^c}\end{cases}$

when $x=2-x \to x=1$ f(x) is continues
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}h(x) & x \in \mathbb{Q}\\g(x) & x \in \mathbb{Q^c}\end{cases}$$ in general ,when $g(x)=h(x)$
in your case

draw $\tan x$ , and 
$x^2+1$ to find crosssections
[image]